# Remotely turning on/off an MMA stick welder while welding, would it fry the machine electronics?

Tags: power

Not exactly an in-depth electronics question but it involves an electronic welding machine, and the answers may come from electronic people not welders. I need to modify an inverter type MMA stick welder machine so I can do spot welding. The way I see this is by modifying a rod holder, to add a push button that will remotely turn the machine on/off. I can place the rod (carbon rod) over the piece, push the button to turn the machine on, let it arc for a second or two, then release the button to turn off the machine, so I can move the rod out without having it arcing around. It works with 20A, carbon arc will reach about 3000 C degrees, so I guess adding the push button to the output wire can't be (not only large button, but also it may arc inside). *My question is: turning on/off the machine this way poses any risks to the electronics? Would it fry?* I'm concerned about the surge inside it when doing this.

Comment: Only the welder manufacturer could answer this.  But, given it is an inverter type, the electronics must actively control the inverter devices.  In the best-case, it would start up after a delay each time.  In the worst-case, it would work once then be damaged.  There might be some way to add a "weld switch" which activates and deactivates the output (not cutting the supply power), but that totally depends on the components inside and could be complex for even a seasoned electronics engineer.  Try asking the manufacturer if the unit can be adapted for spot welding.